# What is the best way to make this 3 view layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know the best way to make a simple layout with 3 TextView.
First TextView can be very long and contain multiple lines, second TextView is small and should be on the right of the first TextView, third TextView is on the right of parent layout with a fixed size.

Here's two rows of this layout that I need:
[image]

Here's example of xml that shows wrong result, because number 22 is on the far right of the row.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="TextView Row 1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="22" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="show" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @MikeM. If TextView 1 is long then it break other 2 views: https://puu.sh/sEr6Q/fadd545bdc.png

Comment: @MikeM. Added the Space, and TextView 1 is still takes all width and just hides all other views if it's too long: https://puu.sh/sErK5/18f44326fd.png

Comment: Yep, I wasn't thinking there. My bad.

Comment: @MikeM. No problem, this looks like an unexpected and frustrating behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, this is a pain. I just can't think of a way to do this with the standard `ViewGroup`s. I'm pretty sure it's gonna take a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:text="TextView Row 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="22" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="show" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If TextView 1 is small then second TextView will be in the center: https://puu.sh/sEFiK/ca8451bb70.png , but I need it after the TextView 1.